# I have class with some Lists, I want to store those two lists to Sqllite in flutter app and retrieve it back

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

How to insert List sqlite in flutter, and read it back. I do not wants to flattering the model because of the sql, as images urls and phones changes, I do not want to lock them down the fixed amount of images or contact nos. I wants the code do the work.

```
class ListingBicycle {
  String uid;
  String listingType;
  String title;
  String description;
  List<String> imagesUrls;
  List<String> contactNumbers;


  ListingBicycle({
    this.uid,
    this.listingType,
    this.title,
    this.description,
    this.imagesUrls,
    this.contactNumbers,
  });
}
```

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite

Comment: Thanks for the link, I read this basic methods, but I am want to convert a LIST of phone numbers or List of imageURLs and insert them as TEXT, when retrieving I want to convert them back to LIST !!!

Comment: save jsonString  @developer-rahul

Comment: do you have any link to see how that is done?  januw a

Answer (score 0):

```dart
class ListingBicycle {
  String uid;
  String listingType;
  String title;
  String description;
  List<String> imagesUrls;
  List<String> contactNumbers;


  ListingBicycle({
    this.uid,
    this.listingType,
    this.title,
    this.description,
    this.imagesUrls,
    this.contactNumbers,
  });

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'uid': uid,
      'listingType': listingType,
      'title': title,
'description': description,
'imagesUrls': jsonEncode(imagesUrls), // to jsonString
'contactNumbers': jsonEncode(contactNumbers),
    };
  }
}
```

insert:

```dart
 await db.insert(
    'dogs',
    dog.toMap(),
    conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
  );
```

List<Map<String, dynamic> into a List

```dart
  return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
    return ListingBicycle(
      uid: maps[i]['uid'],
      listingType: maps[i]['listingType'],
      title: maps[i]['title'],
description: maps[i]['description'],
imagesUrls: jsonDecode(maps[i]['imagesUrls']), // parse jsonString
contactNumbers: jsonDecode(maps[i]['contactNumbers']),
    );
  });
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)